Create an Oracle Text index to a different tablespace
I want to create an index of type context on a tablespace different from the one the table is. Also I want to pass parameters.
The data type of ATTACH_BIN is BLOB.
CREATE INDEX ATT_INDEX ON ATTACH(ATTACH_BIN)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE SYNC(EVERY trunc(sysdate + 1))') TABLESPACE IDX;

ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11000: invalid keyword (
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 186
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 320
00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.


SYNC
Setting the SYNC parameter requires either double quotes or single quotes. For example:
--DROP TABLE ATTACH PURGE;
CREATE TABLE ATTACH(A NUMBER, ATTACH_BIN BLOB);

CREATE INDEX ATT_INDEX ON ATTACH(ATTACH_BIN)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE SYNC(EVERY "TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)")');

Setting Tablespace - Don't Bother
Setting the tablespace for an Oracle Text index is difficult and also doesn't even make sense. The above Oracle Text index is implemented as four tables, a LOB, a JOB, and seven indexes - one of which is for an index organized table, one for the LOB, and one I think is for a function based index? Oracle Text is weird, and the common "rule" about using a separate tablespace for indexes is probably best ignored here.
Run this query to see the supporting objects created to support an Oracle Text index:
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, DBA_OBJECTS.*
FROM DBA_OBJECTS
ORDER BY DBA_OBJECTS.CREATED DESC, DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_TYPE, DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME;

On my system, I see these objects:
OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE
-----------
ATT_INDEX                  INDEX
DR$ATT_INDEX$KD            INDEX
DR$ATT_INDEX$KR            INDEX
DR$ATT_INDEX$X             INDEX
SYS_C0027382               INDEX
SYS_IL0000139300C00006$$   INDEX
SYS_IOT_TOP_139304         INDEX
DR$ATT_INDEX$J             JOB
SYS_LOB0000139300C00006$$  LOB
DR$ATT_INDEX$I             TABLE
DR$ATT_INDEX$K             TABLE
DR$ATT_INDEX$N             TABLE
DR$ATT_INDEX$U             TABLE

Setting Tablespace - ALTER USER
If you really need those objects to be in a separate tablespace, the easiest approach would be to temporarily change the user's default tablespace, run the command, and then set the tablespace back to the original value.
ALTER USER <YOUR_USER> DEFAULT TABLESPACE <NEW_TABLESPACE>;

CREATE INDEX ATT_INDEX  ...

ALTER USER <YOUR_USER> DEFAULT TABLESPACE <OLD_TABLESPACE>;

You're probably thinking, "that sounds like a dumb hack. I don't want to change important user settings and then hopefully remember to change them back." Just wait until you see the alternative...
Setting Tablespace - CTX_DDL
The offical way to define the tablespace is to use CTX_DDL to create a BASIC_STORAGE preference:
begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('mystore', 'BASIC_STORAGE');
end;
/

Then set attributes for that preference:
begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('mystore', 'BASIC_STORAGE');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'I_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'K_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'N_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'U_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'U_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX');
    -- This doesn't, but doesn't throw any errors. I'm sure there's some way to set the LOB tablespace.
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'R_TABLE_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX storage lob (ATTACH_BIN) (tablespace IDX)');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'KD_INDEX_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'KR_INDEX_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX');
    -- Not sure why this does not work.
    -- ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'X_INDEX_CLAUSE', 'tablespace IDX');
end;
/

And finally, build the text index using that preference:
--DROP TABLE ATTACH PURGE;
CREATE TABLE ATTACH(A NUMBER, ATTACH_BIN BLOB);

CREATE INDEX ATT_INDEX ON ATTACH(ATTACH_BIN)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE SYNC(EVERY "TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)") STORAGE MYSTORE');

Which... doesn't quite work for me. Not all of the dependent objects are in the right tablespace. And the number of tables and indexes depends on the features you use, and there are lots of different BASIC_STORAGE attribute tables and indexes listed in the documentation. Maybe if you list all of the attributes, and play around with the BASIC_STORAGE syntax, you can get everything setup right.
It's so annoyingly complicated, I recommend you just change the user's default tablespace. That workaround doesn't look so bad by comparison anymore.

Thank you so much, my problem is that in my current tablespace I don't have enough memory to create this index, thats why I asked about creating to a different tablespace.
I  added datafiles on my current tablespace in order to work before I read your answer. If this doesn't work I will go with your solution about changing user's default tablespace.
